# How toggle function works in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

### Simple toggle function-

```
   $('.simple').toggle(function () {

          //-----------------

        }, 

function () {
         //------------------

        });
    });
```

The thing i am not getting about toggle function is-

when first function ends (`toggle function(){}`), then how it can toggle second function in code?

### How toggle works actually?

Comment: Do you mean how it works internally? You could look at the source code then.

Comment: Are you viewing this from jQuery source or is this your own code. However, I would use if statements if I would have coded it in plain javascript.

Comment: Here's the source for toggle: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js

Comment: you can find a huge explanation of toggle on the jquery site itself...

Comment: Google it, one of results >> http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggle-example-to-display-and-hide-content/

Comment: `.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject) [, handler(eventObject)])` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: COMMENT: If i remember correct, it was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9 . So try to avoid its usage.

Answer (score 1):

> *"when first function ends (toggle function(){}), then how it can toggle second function in code?"*

Without getting into the fine detail - which you can see for yourself in the jQuery.js file - the [`.toggle()` function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) (removed in v1.9) works by binding a click handler to the specified element(s), storing a list of all of the functions that you pass as parameters, and remembering which function in the list should be executed next.

When you first click on the element in question this click handler calls your first function. When you click again it calls the next function in the list. When multiple clicks take it past the end of the list it goes back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `.toggle()` works :

If a div is hidden using `.hide()` or using css (`display:none`), it will display that div. In opposite case, if div is being displayed on screen, it will hide it with `display:none` property.

Comment: That's the wrong `.toggle()`. OP is talking about the _other_ `.toggle()` (now removed) that binds a click handler that alternates between calling multiple functions.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle hides and shows an element alternatively. The function inside toggle is called once the toggling is completed. If you want to use another toggle function you have to call that function inside the first function but you should mention the selector as well. May be this is what you are looking for

```
    $('.simple').toggle(function(){

          $('.simple').toggle();
       });
```

Comment: This would end up toggling twice right, so it ends in the state where it begins. I cannot imagine that he needs this.

Comment: OP is asking about the [other `.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery the toggle() method is used for two different purpose. Here is the details link of this method.http://api.jquery.com/?s=toggle one is for efeect and another is for bind two events at a time, which one is deprecated in version 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

This was taken straight from the jQuery doc http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

> Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed
>   in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named
>   .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the
>   animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments
>   passed.

The function basically worked in conjunction with a click handler. Internally, the code would just simply need to run the handler associated with the 1st, 2nd, [nth], click according to how many clicks had been receieved by the element it was bound to.

I would recommend not using this function.